# Console shows correct value but view's incorrect

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Im getting a json object with HTTPart gem. I need to iterate, convert to integer then do x:

```
data.first["x"] = ["0", "0", "2", "5" ]
```

I need to convert the values to int:

```
arr = data.pluck(:x).map(&:to_i) # How to remove all zeros in one go?
```

I need to remove all `0`:

`arr.delete(0)` then `arr.count{|e| e < 3}`

when I do a puts on `arr.count{|e| e < 3}`, I get `2` but my views show `0`. Huh?

```
@result = arr.count{|e| e < 3} # Shows 2 in console but 0 in views. What's going on?
```

Edit for code view:

```
class ClientController < ApplicationController
 def show
  serpurl = params[:serpurl] # https://serpbook.com/serp/api/?viewkey=2222&auth=2222
  @data = HTTParty.get(serpurl)
  arr = @data.pluck(:x).map(&:to_i).reject(&:zero?)
  @res = arr.count{|e| e < 3}
  puts arr # Shows empty array
 end
end
```

If I copy and paste the above in the rails console, I see expected value.

Comment: By appending `reject(&:zero?)`, makes the array empty for some reason in rails but not so in the console.

Comment: paste `data` and `res` value in the controller.

Comment: data shows the array. res is 0. when in the console, shows 1. I expect to see 1.

Comment: it must be data problem. check every step, if `data` match, then check if `arr `match. add a `ruby-debug` for it, it's very simple to find problem actually.

Comment: focus on this method `pluck(:x)` and array dimension

Comment: Ok, got it. What's the difference with `pluck(:x)` and `pluck("x")`? As I've said, this is a json object. When used `pluck("x")`, all is well.